# Django ORM issue -- objects.get() by pk occasionally fails to find object in DB

Tags: django, rabbitmq, django-orm

We have a Django application that creates a stub object in the DB with some basic default and initial information, then drops a message onto Rabbit MQ to do IO heavy lifting that's required to populate the data for this stub object. We have a separate rabbit MQ consumer that runs as a command line script (wrapped by daemontools - so it does not go down), that processes the messages from rabbit MQ.

So here's what happens - sometimes, when the message comes back (this message has the stub object ID) and we try to read this object using StubObject.objects.get(pk=message['ID']), we get a matching query does not exist exception (the message usually takes about 30 seconds to come back). However when we check in the DB when we get the query does not exist exception, the data for the object is definitely there. This happens once in about 5 times we process the message. We have no idea why this could happen and are trying to solve this. It's particularly strange that it only fails sometimes. Any ideas?

We tried to print connection.queries but no output was printed.

The rabbit MQ consumer that is attempting the save runs outside of the standard django python files, so we need to import a bunch of stuff to give it access to the ORM (not sure if perhaps the problem is with how we do this). Code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import os
sys.path.append('/myproject')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myproject.settings'

from django.db import connection
from django.core import serializers
from django.core.management import setup_environ
from register_obj.models import Obj
from myproject import settings
import datetime
import json
import pika

setup_environ(settings)

conn = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
channel = conn.channel()

print '[*] Waiting for responses. To exit press CTRL+C'

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print "[x] Received %r" % (body,)
    objDict = json.loads(body)
        print objDict
    try:
        obj = Obj.objects.get(pk=objDict["id"])
        print connection.queries
    except Exception, e:
        print datetime.datetime.now()
        print "Error occurred, could not find obj by ID - "
        print objDict["id"]
        print e
        print '################Query##############'
        print connection.queries

    obj.updateDict(objDict)

    # Save the obj data
    obj.save()

channel.basic_consume(callback,
        queue='myQueue',
        no_ack=True)

channel.start_consuming()
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually, this is due to a race condition between your Django app committing transactions and your queue consumer.

Most likely, you are running your Django app set up to automatically wrap each request in a transaction. Ie, it begins a transaction, does all the database operations, then commits once the request is handled and sent back to the browser (or rolls back if anything throws an exception). Somewhere in there you create your stub object, then put a task on the queue with that stub's id. The problem comes when the queue is empty so your consumer gets the task right away. Meanwhile, there's a little delay on the Django side while it's finishing off the rest of the request (even just sending the bytes down the wire to the browser and closing the connection can take a while) and the transaction is still open. Until the transaction is closed, that object's row in the database won't be available to other transactions, like your consumer.

The solution is to switch to manual transaction handling for the views that put tasks on the queue and commit before putting it on the queue.

It would look something like this:

```
from django.django.db import transaction

@transaction.commit_manually
def some_view(request):
    try:
        # do some work...
        stub = Obj.objects.create(...)
    except:
        transaction.rollback()
        raise
    else:
        transaction.commit()
        add_task_to_queue(obj_id=stub.id)
        # finish serving request
        ...
```

Of course, once you are manually handling transactions, you need to be very careful that you are always committing or rolling back any transaction that you open.

Comment: You should probably also mention how RabbitMQ supports its own transactions so if he is sending a bunch of messages he will have to manage that also: http://www.rabbitmq.com/semantics.html . Spring framework is the only framework that I know that happily marries DB transactions and RabbitMQ transactions.